# torchtext field with values converted to ids got error integer is required

Tags: python, pytorch, torchtext

I followed this tutorial 
http://www.programmersought.com/article/2609385756/

to create a TabularDataset with data that already tokenized and converted to ids and I do not want to use vocab or build vocab because the data is numerical

so I defined my field variable as:

```
myField = Field(tokenize= x_tokenize, use_vocab=False, sequential=True)
train,val, test = data.TabularDataset.splits(path='./', train=train_path, validation=valid_path, test=test_path ,format='csv', fields=data_fields, skip_header=True)
```

train output:

```
print(vars(train[0])['src'])
#output this [101, 3177, 3702, 11293, 1116, 102]
```

and I used a BucketIterator:

```
train_iter= BucketIterator(train,
                       batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
                       device = DEVICE,
                       sort_key=lambda x: (len(x.src), len(x.trg)), 
                       train=True,
                       batch_size_fn=batch_size_fn,
                       repeat=False)
```

when I run this code:

```
batch = next(iter(train_iter))
```

I got 
TypeError: an integer is required (got type list)

---

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 batch = next(iter(train_iter))
>
> 3 frames
>   /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torchtext/data/iterator.py in
>   **iter**(self)
>       155                     else:
>       156                         minibatch.sort(key=self.sort_key, reverse=True)
>   --> 157                 yield Batch(minibatch, self.dataset, self.device)
>       158             if not self.repeat:
>       159                 return
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torchtext/data/batch.py in
>   **init**(self, data, dataset, device)
>        32                 if field is not None:
>        33                     batch = [getattr(x, name) for x in data]
>   ---> 34                     setattr(self, name, field.process(batch, device=device))
>        35 
>        36     @classmethod
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torchtext/data/field.py in
>   process(self, batch, device)
>       199         """
>       200         padded = self.pad(batch)
>   --> 201         tensor = self.numericalize(padded, device=device)
>       202         return tensor
>       203
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torchtext/data/field.py in
>   numericalize(self, arr, device)
>       321                 arr = self.postprocessing(arr, None)
>       322 
>   --> 323         var = torch.tensor(arr, dtype=self.dtype, device=device)
>       324 
>       325         if self.sequential and not self.batch_first:
>
> TypeError: an integer is required (got type list)

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide the pad_token while declaring the Field.

Change this

```
myField = Field(tokenize= x_tokenize, use_vocab=False, sequential=True)
```

to

```
myField = Field(tokenize= x_tokenize, use_vocab=False, sequential=True, pad_token=0)
```